# Using ggplot and melt function

Tags: r, ggplot2, melt

I am following the examples lied out below (https://rpubs.com/thinh_ha/londonhouseprice). I am attempting to use the group by part.

```
 by_pt <- select(df, realprice1, class) %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarise(Count=n(), Mean.Price=mean(realprice1), St.Dev.Price=sd(realprice1), Median.Price=median(realprice1))


ggplot(melt(by_pt), aes(x=value, y=variable, fill=class)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales='free') +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat='identity', width=0.3)
```

The first part of my code creates a data frame called by_pt which has two rows and 5 columns. The first column is class which the first being Sole and the Second Joint. The remaining four are the stats creates in the summarise function.

However, when I use ggplot I get the following error.

Using class as id variables
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Just an idea: you might try to use a different name than "class", because "class()" is a function.

Comment: I tried this but still running into the same issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please check those links and re-consider your question accordingly. You will be way more likely to get help.